# Mongodb aggregation, group and then count

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have jobs and candidates have applied on each jobs. Here is sample of just one job.

```
  {
     "_id": ObjectId("5a9e625c748a563a80e5d86a"),
     "job_title": "Software developer",
     "companyId": ObjectId("5a9e625c748a563a80e5889ds")
     "applications" : [ 
            {
                "applied" : true,
                "shortlisted" : false,
                "interviewed" : false,
                "offered" : false,
                "hired" : false,
                "rejected" : false
            },
            {
                "applied" : true,
                "shortlisted" : true,
                "interviewed" : false,
                "offered" : false,
                "hired" : false,
                "rejected" : false
            },
            {
                "applied" : true,
                "shortlisted" : true,
                "interviewed" : true,
                "offered" : false,
                "hired" : false,
                "rejected" : false
            },
            {
                "applied" : true,
                "shortlisted" : true,
                "interviewed" : true,
                "offered" : false,
                "hired" : false,
                "rejected" : false
            },
            {
                "applied" : true,
                "shortlisted" : true,
                "interviewed" : false,
                "offered" : false,
                "hired" : false,
                "rejected" : true
            },

        ]

    }
```

A candidate can go through stages like Applied, Shortlisted, interviewed .....

So What I want to get is total number of applicants are in each stages.

Result something like this :

```
{
  applied: 1,
  shortlisted: 1,
  interviewed: 2,
  offered: 0,
  hired: 0,
  rejected: 1
}
```

Here is how i tried to write query

```
  Job.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        companyId : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id),
        active: true
      }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$applications"
    },
    {
      $replaceRoot : {
        newRoot : "$applications"
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
          _id : {
            applied : "$applied",
            shortlisted : "$shortlisted",
            interviewed : "$interviewed",
            offered : "$offered",
            hired : "$hired",
            rejected : "$rejected"
          },
          applied: {$sum: "_id"},
          // shortlisted: {$sum: "shortlisted"},
          // interviewed: {$sum: "interviewed"},
          // offered: {$sum: "offered"},
          // hired: {$sum: "hired"},
          // rejected: {$sum: "rejected"},
      }
    }
  ])
```

This is for total counts irrespective of jobs. I also would want to know count of applicants in each stages against of a job.

**Edited :**

```
{
            "applied" : true,
            "shortlisted" : false,
            "interviewed" : false,
            "offered" : false,
            "hired" : false,
            "rejected" : false,
            "rejectedComment" : "",
            "notes" : [],
            "documents" : [],
            "assessment" : [],
            "interviewSchedule" : [],
            "references" : [],
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a9fc2b6e80e10405ce612d6"),
            "talentId" : ObjectId("5a8e7da63925a10b68ea08dd"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-03-07T10:45:10.675Z"),
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-03-07T10:45:10.675Z")
        }
```

**updated**

```
{
      $match: {
        companyId : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id),
        active: true
      }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$applications"
    },
    {
      $replaceRoot : {
        newRoot : "$applications"
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
          _id : '',
          // "applied":{"$sum":{"$cond":{$and:[{$eq:["$applications", {applied: true, shortlisted: false , interviewed: false, offered: false, hired: false, rejected: false}]},1,0]}}},
          "applied": {"$sum": {"$cond": {$and: [{$eq:["$applications", {applied: true, shortlisted: false , interviewed: false, offered: false, hired: false, rejected: false}]},1,0]}]}}
          //   shortlisted : {"$applied.shortlisted" : false},
          //   interviewed : {"$applied.interviewed" : false},
          //   offered : {"$applied.offered" : false},
          //   hired : {"$applied.hired" : false},
          // "rejected":{"$sum":{"$cond":[{$eq:["$applications", {rejected: true}]},1,0]}},
          // },
          // "applied": {
          //   "$sum": 1
          // }
        // }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator inside the [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) to count the application in each stage.

Something like

```
Jobs.aggegate([
  {"$match":{"companyId":mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id),"active":true}},
  {"$unwind":"$applications"},
  {"$group":{
    "_id": some group key,
    "applied":{"$sum":{"$cond":["$applied",1,0]}}
    ...other stages
  }
])
```

Comment: Thank you veeram for replying, I am actually new to mongodb. Can you please tell me what 1, 0 in $cond and some group key. Why do i need that. Thanks

Comment: no problem. what is your group by key ? job id/companyId right ? 1, 0 is to output 1 when the stage is true else 0 when false and $sum to count specific stage across the group id.

Comment: {applied: true, shotlisted: false , other aslo false .....}, {applied: true, shotlisted: true , other false .....}, {applied: true, shotlisted: true , interviewed: true and other false.....}.

Comment: sorry i dont follow you. do you have a specific question ?

Comment: i have to group by {applied: true, shotlisted: false , other aslo false .....}, {applied: true, shotlisted: true , other false .....}, {applied: true, shotlisted: true , interviewed: true and other false.....}. These are basically applications made by applicants on single job. So i need to determine that how many candidates are in applied stage , shortlisted stage, interviewed stage ...... and in rejected stage. $cond makes sense but i dont know how to write

Comment: why not just save the single status ? why do you have to save all the status for each row ?

Comment: {applied: true, applied_date: always_will_be , shotlisted: false , shortlisted_date: depend_if_shortlited_otherwise_null........ } .To keep a track of when candidate has moved across different stages .... Major reason i come from mysql background and i have to define schema...  And right now i am using ODM mongoosejs so here also defined. Can't i just give other condition attribute along with what u have written?

Comment: Sure. `"applied":{"$sum":{"$cond":[{$eq:["$application", {applied: true, shotlisted: false , other aslo false .....}]},1,0]}}`

Comment: Hi Sorry little late , it says applied : 0 . Though i have candidates in applied stage                                                                                         "applied":{"$sum":{"$cond":[{$eq:["$applications", {applied: true, shortlisted: false , interviewed: false, offered: false, hired: false, rejected: false}]},1,0]}}

Comment: Do your application have more fields ?

Comment: You have to write $and expression. Something like inside cond. `{$and:[{$eq:["$applications.applied", true]}, {$eq:["$applications.shotlisted", false]} ...`

Comment: i am doing same as u told i always get 0 but i stil have data

Comment: Try `"applied": {"$sum": {"$cond": [{$and: [{$eq:["$applications.applied", true]},{$eq:["$applications.shortlisted", false]},
{$eq:["$applications.interviewed", false]},
{$eq:["$applications.offered", false]},
{$eq:["$applications.hired", false]},
{$eq:["$applications.rejected", false]}]},1,0]}}`. Repeat for other stages.

Comment: still getting 0

Comment: here is tested version. it returns 1 for me. for the data you have. `{"$group":{
    "_id": null,
"applied": {"$sum": {"$cond": [{"$and": [{"$eq":["$applications.applied", true]},{"$eq":["$applications.shortlisted", false]}, {"$eq":["$applications.interviewed", false]}, {"$eq":["$applications.offered", false]}, {"$eq":["$applications.hired", false]}, {"$eq":["$applications.rejected", false]}]},1,0]}}
  }}`

Comment: Doesn't work for me. even though i am just trying with [{"$eq":["$applications.applied", true]}]}

Comment: can u send me exact query for which u got 1.

Comment: i didnt get $group stage only mean?

Comment: Try `Job.aggregate([{"$group":{ "_id": null, "applied": {"$sum": {"$cond": [{"$and": [{"$eq":["$applications.applied", true]},{"$eq":["$applications.shortlisted", false]}, {"$eq":["$applications.interviewed", false]}, {"$eq":["$applications.offered", false]}, {"$eq":["$applications.hired", false]}, {"$eq":["$applications.rejected", false]}]},1,0]}} }}]) `

Comment: finally Thank you so  so much Veeram for your time. Learned new things.  It worked with the same query . I was making some typo somewhere Thank you

Comment: I think i was writing $applications even after '$unwind'ing

Answer (score 0):

you can try without `$unwind` and `$group` using `$reduce` with `$cond`itional `$sum`

```
db.jobs.aggregate([
    //{$match : {}},
    {$project : {
        data : {
            $reduce : {
                input : "$applications",
                initialValue : {
                    "applied" : 0,
                    "shortlisted" : 0,
                    "interviewed" : 0,
                    "offered" : 0,
                    "hired" : 0,
                    "rejected" : 0
                },
                in : {
                    "applied" : {$sum : ["$$value.applied", {$cond : ["$$this.applied", 1, 0]}]},
                    "shortlisted" : {$sum : ["$$value.shortlisted", {$cond : ["$$this.shortlisted", 1, 0]}]},
                    "interviewed" : {$sum : ["$$value.interviewed", {$cond : ["$$this.interviewed", 1, 0]}]},
                    "offered" : {$sum : ["$$value.offered", {$cond : ["$$this.offered", 1, 0]}]},
                    "hired" : {$sum : ["$$value.hired", {$cond : ["$$this.hired", 1, 0]}]},
                    "rejected" : {$sum : ["$$value.rejected", {$cond : ["$$this.rejected", 1, 0]}]}
                }
            }
        }
    }},
    {$replaceRoot : {newRoot : "$data"}}
]).pretty()
```

result

```
{
    "applied" : 5,
    "shortlisted" : 4,
    "interviewed" : 2,
    "offered" : 0,
    "hired" : 0,
    "rejected" : 1
}
>
```